# Sphinx (documentation tool): set tab width in output

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How do you set tab width in HTML output of Sphinx code snippets highlighted by Pygments?
By default it is the annoying 8, but I want 4.
Did not find a word about this setting in Sphinx conf.py.

Comment: Agreed with S. Lott, even in the Java world you can use spaces instead of tabs. http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc3.html#262

Comment: It may not be so easy for some to just switch to spaces though: your entire team's codebase could well use tabs, and supplying documentation that uses spaces is inconsistent. Changing all of the code to use one over the other is impractical and potentially destructive. Sphinx is useful for many different languages and environments. The argument that the best narrative documentation tools around aren't broken if they don't support tabs, it's your code that's broken because "PEP8, that's why" is shortsighted and counterproductive at best.

Comment: Also, I'm aware that tab substitution happens in docutils, not in sphinx, but sphinx is severely affected by the problem and should take some responsibility for dealing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a Sphinx Extension. [Add your custom Lexer](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/appapi.html?highlight=pygments#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_lexer), and apply it with [VisibleWhitespaceFilter](http://pygments.org/docs/filters/).

Comment: I updated my Sphinx to 0.6.3 and Pygments to 1.1.1 (pygmentize -V).
Touched all my files, then added this to conf.py:

def setup(app):
    from sphinx.highlighting import lexers
    from pygments.lexers.compiled import JavaLexer
    from pygments.filters import VisibleWhitespaceFilter

    myLexer = JavaLexer()
    myLexer.add_filter(VisibleWhitespaceFilter(spaces='!'));
    app.add_lexer('java', myLexer);

This replaced all tabs in my Java code with eight "!" and all spaces
with "!" as expected.
When I tried option tabs='!', nothing changed.
When I tried option tabsize=4, nothing changed.

Comment: It seems like tabs have been replaced with spaces somewhere earlier in
the chain.
So, I tried to add this filter to other lexers (rest, none) [with
lexers['rest'].add_filter(...)], but none of that had any effect on
tabs or tabsize.

Answer (score 3):

Add something like this to your conf.py:

```
import re

def process_docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    spaces_pat = re.compile(r"( {8})")
    ll = []
    for l in lines:
        ll.append(spaces_pat.sub("    ",l))
    lines[:] = ll

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', process_docstring)
```

See also Sphinx [Docstring preprocessing](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, and with Sphinx v6.1.3 I have solved this problem by including a file named `docutils.conf` in the source folder, with the only content:

```
[restructuredtext parser]
tab_width: 4
```

and it worked!

I found this trick [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5450#issuecomment-422428392)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on sphinx-dev group and it turns out it's a problem with Docutils which is used by Sphinx. Docutils replace all tabs with 8 spaces and currently there is no way to change that value from Sphinx.

http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/35b8071ffe9a8feb

The only feasible solution seems to be to follow the advice from S.Lott and John Paulett in comments to my question -- use spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I've changes the font-size of the white-space in my custom.css This is a easy tweak and works very well. This will only change the code-block and nothing else. Which is what I wanted.

_static/custon.css

```
div.highlight pre .w {
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

Note: The solution of Docstring preprocessing was messing up my python code docstring which was causing error's while build.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way: add the following to `conf.py`

```py
def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', process_docstring)

def env_before_read_docs(app, env, docnames):
    env.settings["tab_width"] = 4
```

I'm not sure where the documentation is (so there's no guarantee this API is stable), but there's a comment in `sphinx/environment/__init__.py`:

```
# the docutils settings for building
self.settings = default_settings.copy()
```

which is precisely what we want here.